# How to delete static files or directory from heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, bash, heroku

I dynamically create folder with images in my public directory that looks something like this `public/indiv/compa/ferfw432ervr12/test.png`. I want to delete the `indiv` directory. I tried doing heroku run bash. and used `rm` to delete the directory. I did `ls` after and I could not find the file so I thought everything was good but I could still see the image when I go to the url so I did `heroku run bash` and the files are still there. I want them gone.

I also did something like this:

```
var deleteFolderRecursive = function(path) {
  if( fs.existsSync(path) ) {
    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(function(file,index){
      var curPath = path + "/" + file;
      if(fs.lstatSync(curPath).isDirectory()) { // recurse
        deleteFolderRecursive(curPath);
      } else { // delete file
        fs.unlinkSync(curPath);
      }
    });
    fs.rmdirSync(path);
  }
};
```

It looks It deleted files from local but not heroku even after I did `git push heroku master`

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) works.

Whatever files you push to Heroku exist in the filesystem of any and every dyno you run.
It sounds like you have a web dyno that dynamically creates a directory with various image files. Probably not a very good idea on Heroku, unless you really only need those dynamically generated files to be available only to the dyno instance that created them, and only for the duration of that dyno instance's [current cycle](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting).
It is highly unlikely that you have a use case that really justifies doing that, but let's say you do. Going in and doing a "heroku run bash" simply creates a new, "one off" dyno instance, which has its own ephemeral file system, that is completely separate from the ephemeral filesystem of your Web dyno.
So, erasing a file or directory in your one-off dyno will have absolutely no impact on the behaviour of your web dyno.

Comment: `It is highly unlikely that you have a use case that really justifies doing that` I will tell you why I'm doing it. maybe you can tell me if it is "justified" to do or I will just give you more information. I use the feed dialog button on facebook for a review site. After the user enters a review and clicks the fb share button,  `fb.api` is triggered that's where I tell it to find a picture that was just put together on the share button click. I tell the fb api to go to that individual pic that was just created. I thought that would be good since it is standard to keep pics in public folder. .

Comment: I think you are saying that I shouldn't put the images on heroku. I think your saying if I have multiple dynos it would cause problems. should I use something like http://cloudinary.com/ instead. I have to make sure the images get loaded to cloudinary before FB API is called. btw, I deleted the files by using "fs-path" npmj

Comment: As you mentioned correctly, using the ephemeral file system won't work if you have multiple dynos, and won't be reliable for your use case even with one dyno, since your one dyno can recycle at any time without warning, and the file you stored is gone. You should be using some external backing service for your images. I am not familiar with cloudinary.com, but that might be an appropriate choice. Take a look on Heroku Elements for other possibilities. Good luck!